How can I declare a rust function that can call Control::set_h_size_flags(...) on arguments of type Gd<GridContainer> or Gd<SubViewportContainer>?
I have a chunk of code that I want to turn into a function:
    node.set_h_size_flags(SizeFlags::EXPAND_FILL);
    node.set_v_size_flags(SizeFlags::EXPAND_FILL);
    node.set_anchor(Side::TOP, 0.0);
    node.set_anchor(Side::BOTTOM, 0.0);
    node.set_anchor(Side::LEFT, 0.0);
    node.set_anchor(Side::RIGHT, 0.0);

I want to be able to call it on nodes that are Gd<GridContainer>, or Gd<SubViewportContainer> or Gd<SubViewport> or anything else that has the necessary methods.
RustRover tells me that these methods are implemented on the Control struct which is not pub .  It is not obvious to me what magic Rust is performing to call a Control method on a Gd .
Consequently I am having difficulty figuring out what type to declare in the function signature for node.
fn gd_expand_fill(
    node: &mut Gd<
        GridContainer, // not generic enough
    >,
) {


Control is pub, but I assume you mean the Control member of GridContainer and so on.
The "magic" is that these types implement Deref with Target = Container, and Container implements Deref with Target = Control.  (Since the methods here take &mut self they must also implement DerefMut, and indeed they do.)  This allows you to use any of the methods of Container and Control on these structs, by Rust's auto-deref coercion.  (Control further auto-derefs to several more types, but we don't use those types here.)
This coercion is also applied when you pass a reference of a type implementing Deref to a function that accepts a reference.  If the type of the reference doesn't match, the compiler will see if it can get to that type through the available chain of Deref/DerefMut implementations.
All this means is that you can do exactly what you want by just taking &mut Control.
fn gd_expand_fill(node: &mut Control)

Then you can call this with a Gd<GridContainer> like so:
let mut grid_container: Gd<GridContainer> = todo!();
gd_expand_fill(&mut grid_container);

(Gd<T> is a box-like type and it implements Deref<Target = T> and DerefMut as well.)
